# Link containing variable as a get argument php

Tags: php

I am working on a registration system that sends an email to the user with an activation link, using the username they provided. I cannot seem to figure out how to append the variable as a get argument. The email sends, but my link is not showing up right. Am I using the wrong syntax?

```
$message = "Thank you for creating an account. Please activate it now here : <a href=\"http://cts.gruv.org/jstudent/activate.php?username=".$_GET['user']."\"></a>";
```

I have `user` declared as such:

```
$user = $_POST['newUserName'];
```

which is grabbing the information provided in the form by the registrant. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Activating users by their username is extremely stupid idea.

Comment: It's just for practice. I'm the only user going to be registering. Also just using a text file to store info right now, which I also know is stupid. Just practice

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some text within the 'a' tag. something like this:

`$message = "Thank you for creating an account. Please activate it now <a href=\"http://cts.gruv.org/jstudent/activate.php?username=".$_GET['user']."\">here</a>";`

Comment: `Thank you for creating an account. Please activate it now <a href="http://cts.gruv.org/jstudent/activate.php?username=">here</a>` is the ouput from the email with that. About what I've been getting.

Comment: Need it to show the username in the link and link to it.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if I'm understanding correclty. But you might simply need to do this: `$message = "Thank you for creating an account. Please activate it now <a href=\"http://cts.gruv.org/jstudent/activate.php?username=".$user."\">here</a>";`

Answer (score 0):

There is no text in your anchor tags. The link won't show unless you put something there I.e

```
<a href ="...">my link</a>
```